# boost libraries fail compiling for c++11 and works for c++98

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm having a problem trying to compile a project using `c++11` standard, because of `boost` libraries. 
I have no problem when I compile it using `c++98` standard, and I don't understand why.

I use next command to compile (c++11):

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DENABLE_IPV6 -DTIXML_USE_STL -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED -I. -I/usr/include -o obj/test.o ../src/net/common/test.cpp
```

To compile using `c++98` standard, I use same command, except I remove `-std` flag. I use `g++ 5.4.0`. So, it uses `c++98` standard, by default

Its output (`c++11`):

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/throw_error.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from ../src/net/test.h:36,
                 from ../src/net/common/test.cpp:32:
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:190:32: error:   overriding ‘virtual const char* boost::system::error_category::name() const noexcept’
       virtual const char *     name() const BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT = 0;
                                ^
```

I'm probably wrong, but it looks like `boost` isn't able to detect I set flags for `c++11`
That's why I tried to see which macros are defined, using

```
g++ -E -dM -pipe -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DENABLE_IPV6 -DTIXML_USE_STL -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED -I. -I/usr/include ../src/net/common/test.cpp > obj/test_11.txt
```

I did the same for `c++98`. Its output:

`c++98`:

```
// it does not set __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#define BOOST_NOEXCEPT 
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT BOOST_NOEXCEPT
```

`c++11`:

```
#define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ 1 //It sets c++11 macro 
#define BOOST_NOEXCEPT noexcept
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT BOOST_NOEXCEPT
```

It seems ok, isn't it? It defines `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` as `noexcept` in `c++11`, and as blank in `c++98`

I'm not expert in `c++` (neither `c++11` nor `c++98`), so I'm quite lost here. Any idea?

**Remark**
Boost Libraries version (`/usr/include/boost/version.hpp`): `#define BOOST_VERSION 106000`

Comment: have you tried with -std=c++11 instead of gnu++11?

Comment: `c++11` is an dialect for `gnu++11`

Comment: never used gnu++11, but there are few differences about it, it is worth a try

Comment: No, there are not... check `man g++`, and you'll see that `gnu++11` and `gnu++0x` are dialects for `c++11`

Answer (score 0):

According to your log file the macro `BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT` hasn't been set yet. Because you haven't provided the full source code I can only *assume* that the order of includes of the boost headers is wrong. If the order would be correct the macro `BOOST_SYSTEM_NOEXCEPT` would have been defined correct (looked into some boost source files which are involved).

However, if we are only using `#include < asio.hpp>`  more information about your source code etc will be needed.

Regardless of all this stuff I would recommend to update to the latest version of boost.

Comment: Ok, it's true.. I made a mistake copying the macros. I just correct it.

Comment: Anyway, it solves nothing... keep in mind that `gcc -E -dM` generates a text file over 1Mb. I had to copy and paste the lines I needed to show and I switched the order... it means nothing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132410/discussion-between-arthur-m-and-albert).

Comment: look onto my changes